# How to stop a WPF WebBrowser from loading the page?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I see methods for GoBack, GoForward, Refresh, and Navigate, but no "Stop" or "Cancel". How do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

Use can use the `InvokeScript` method over `WebBrowser` control to stop page navigation.

```
yourWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is a bit tricky you should get IWebBrowser2 interface from the WPF WebBrowser control, after that you may get access to some methods that not publicly exposed in this control.

More details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.90).aspx (Getting to the native IWebBrowser2)

Comment: Ensure that your .NET version within the Microsoft help pages is set to v3.5, or else you may not see the required comment - the .NET 4 version does not show it.